# Save VB data entry to Text File

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vba

So, I wrote this code that takes in information entered by a user.

```
    Public Class Patient
    Private Sub Patient_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Label1.Text = "First Name:"
    Label2.Text = "Last Name:"
    Label3.Text = "Address: "
    Label4.Text = "City:"
    Label5.Text = "Province: "
    Label6.Text = "Postal Code: "
    Label7.Text = "Health Card Number: "

    If (CollectionIndexValue <> -1) Then
        Dim existingPatient As New PatientObject4

        existingPatient = PatientCollection(CollectionIndexValue)

        TextBox1.Text = existingPatient.Firstname
        TextBox2.Text = existingPatient.LastName
        TextBox3.Text = existingPatient.Address
        TextBox4.Text = existingPatient.City
        TextBox5.Text = existingPatient.Province
        TextBox6.Text = existingPatient.PostalCode
        TextBox7.Text = existingPatient.HealthCardNumber
        Button1.Text = "Save"

    Else
        Button1.Text = "Add"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If (TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or
       TextBox5.Text = "" Or TextBox6.Text = "" And TextBox7.Text = "") Then
        Label8.Text = "All fields must be populated"
    Else
        If (Button1.Text.ToUpper() = "ADD") Then
            Dim PatientObject As New PatientObject4

            PatientObject.Firstname = TextBox1.Text
            PatientObject.LastName = TextBox2.Text
            PatientObject.Address = TextBox2.Text
            PatientObject.City = TextBox4.Text
            PatientObject.Province = TextBox5.Text
            PatientObject.HealthCardNumber = TextBox7.Text

            PatientCollection.Add(PatientObject)

            Label8.Text = "Patient Added"
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
            TextBox4.Text = ""
            TextBox5.Text = ""
            TextBox6.Text = ""
            TextBox7.Text = ""

        Else
            Dim PatientSave As New PatientObject4
            PatientSave.Firstname = TextBox1.Text
            PatientSave.LastName = TextBox2.Text
            PatientSave.Address = TextBox3.Text
            PatientSave.City = TextBox4.Text
            PatientSave.Province = TextBox5.Text
            PatientSave.PostalCode = TextBox6.Text
            PatientSave.LastName = TextBox7.Text

            PatientCollection(CollectionIndexValue) = PatientSave

            Label8.Text = "Patient Saved"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

If I want this information to be save to a text file (create a new text file) when a new patient is added. How would go about doing that? I tried to google it, but it a bit hard when you don't know what you're looking for.

Any help/ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. This is just a snippet of a larger code. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to save this to a text file?  If a user is going to enter more than one patient, how are you proposing to recall the information later on?  Surely this is a case where you would want to store the information in a table in a database.

Comment: I already have a system for recalling the information (all set-up) later on. This is just a snippet of the code. Plus, I want to store it in a text file, because I just want to know how I could use VB to create an external file saves on my computer.  I want to know who that would work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything file related, look to the [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace. IE; File, StringWriter, TextWriter. There is a quick and simple example for File [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Suggestion for future, though:  VB.NET/VisualStudio <> VBA.  Best to tag questions appropriately.